# Как найти все ссылки на странице?

Tags: php

Необходимо найти все ссылки на странице и записать их параметры (href, rel, название и т.д.). Что можно сделать?

Answer (score 6):

Почти как jquery :)

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

**Добавлено.**

```
// Создать DOM из URL
$html = file_get_html('http://yandex.ru/');

// Найти все ссылки 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) 
       echo $element->href . '<br>';
```

Comment: Ого 6 лет назад, я думал это вопрос- шутка. Или вопрос сбой сети.